# What does "shielding of" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does "shielding of A" mean?

1) Protection from A

2) Protection of A from something else

Examples from web:

> 1) EMF 70 is a premium precious metal window film for shielding of windows and glass surfaces from high-frequency radiation (HF).
>
> 2) NEW-DAYLITE™ from Swiss-Shield® is a highly-transparent Trevira® fabric for the shielding of high-frequency electromagnetic fields (HF).

Are both correct?

Answer (score 1):

“The shielding of A” most commonly means protecting A from something (that is, your option 2).

For example, “The shielding of your barbecue from the weather with a fabric cover, roofing, etc. will prolong its useful life.”

However, you have also identified how constructions like, “the shielding of weather from your barbecue” are possible. As a learner, I would not recommend that you use “shielding” in this unusual way. It is correct but it is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

**Shielding** can be applied either to what is protected from some influence or to the source of that influence (if not to both).

**Example 1** is about *protecting* A (by shielding it) from something else.

**Example 2** is about *isolating* A (by shielding it as a source of an undesirable influence) from *everything else* (which is thus *protected*).